# Is Java worth learning in my late thirties?

Tags: java

First I want to say is that I am 37 years old and not from programmer background (actually from biology). And my question is should I start learning java? I have coded in php and javascript for a year and  a half. Every answer would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
Bobi.

Comment: What does age have to do with it? The real question is, what do you want to do with Java?

Comment: Is this like asking; is it still worth learning new things even though I am half way through my life?"

Comment: Hmmm, you're in your “late forties” but still only 37?

Comment: No. If you have to ask, then, no.

Comment: @EdSwangren: That would imply that his life will end when he's only 2 × 37 = 74. That's sad…

Comment: If you were 42 this would be totally different!!!!

Comment: http://www.yodajeff.com/multimedia/sounds/episode5/to_old.wav

Comment: I started Java at age 36, coming from a math background, without any programming background outside of ForTran 77, and that unused since college.  It's working out well for me so far.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

( what else can I say? )

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what your motivation for learning it is. Do you want a language that gets you a job easily, a language that gets you an interesting job, a language to hack in for fun, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

If you enjoyed coding in php and javascript, then you probably have discovered the "programmer mindset" and I would say go for it. You're never to old to learn interesting new things!

If, on the other hand, you hated the coding you have done already then learning a different language probably won't help.

Comment: +1 for never too old to learn interesting new things. That said, a person who asks a question like that is probably not open to learning, as the question implies that the asker finds learning to be a chore rather than the enjoyable process of discovery that it is.

Answer (score 1):

Learn whatever language they're teaching at your local community college (by attending programming classes that is).

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do. If you are looking to develop on mobile applications (Android or BlackBerry) or if you want to write JSP or GRails web applications go for it! Age or background shouldn't stop you!